Flyway:The parsed SQL statement is incomplete
it's my sql file
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateIndex;
CREATE PROCEDURE updateIndex()
BEGIN
DECLARE key1_value INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tname varchar(30);
DECLARE loopNum INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE tmp_result CURSOR FOR select key1, name,count(*) from test_flyway group by key1,name having count(*) > 1;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET flag = 0;
OPEN tmp_result;
WHILE flag = 1 DO
FETCH tmp_result INTO key1_value, tname, loopNum;
    WHILE i < loopNum DO
        UPDATE test_flyway set name = CONCAT(name,'(', i,')')   WHERE   id = ( SELECT tmp.id FROM ( SELECT id from test_flyway WHERE key1 = key1_value and name = tname LIMIT 1 ) tmp );
        SET i = i + 1;
    END while;
    SET i = 1;
END while;
END;


I omitted some unnecessary code.

SQL migration failed, here is the program output

You have an error in your SQL syntax...

But it runs normally on the MySQL client.
So, I debugged the code and found that there was an issue with the parsed SQL, only parsing to the first END WHILD.
My flyway version is 7.15.0. I guess it may be related to the version, so which version should I switch to?

I'd suggest first taking the latest version and seeing if the issue is still there.

I will give it a try tomorrow. I just want to upgrade to the smallest version to control the impact on the program code

I have sloved this problem, but not by upgrading the version of flyway(Because it may cause other problems, like not support mysql5.7)
I added DELIMITER $$ and END $$ before and after the SQL script, this becomes feasible.Although DELIMITER was not added when writing the SQL script before, it is still feasible

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
